# Upper bound for some of exponents

Tags: calculus

Let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^N \in \mathbb{R}^+$. I'm looking for an upper bound on $\sum_{i=1}^Ne^{-a_i}$ which is better than $N\max_ie^{-a_i}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything known about the sequence?  Like monotonacity or anything like that?

Comment: @SimpleArt I think monotonicity does not matter. Since we're doing sum anyways. So, without loss of generality we can assume that the sequence is decreasing for example.

Comment: No, it does make a difference.  For example, using monotonicity, I can then set upper and lower bounds by considering $\int_1^ne^{-a_x}dx$

Comment: @MehdiJafarniaJahromi well unless you tell us more about the sequence, there isn't going to be a better upper bound.